# How to permanent route in Redhat Linux 6.4

Tags: debian, centos, fedora, rhel

I tried **route add -net 192.168.3.115 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.3.1** but it was not working after reboot , can someone tell me how it works after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have statically configured network settings in your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` file(s), then you can configure static routes in the corresponding `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-*` file(s).

The filename should be chosen to match the interface the route is going to apply to, e.g. if your `eth0` interface is used to contact the 192.168.3.1 gateway, then the route should be defined in file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`.

There are two possible ways to specify your static route.

Old syntax: (the way older RedHat versions did it)

```
ADDRESS0=192.168.3.115 
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY0=192.168.3.1
```

New syntax: (basically similar to how the `ip route` command accepts it)

```
192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.3.1
```

Source: [RHEL 6 Deployment Guide, Chapter 11.5: *Configuring static routes in `ifcfg` files*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-configuring_static_routes_in_ifcfg_files)

Comment: Ok thank you i will try  this way also.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. Since networking is unreliable, and your system might be connected to a different network when networking starts, routes don't survive reboots.

You'll have to do the `route add ...` as part of system/networking startup, or configure the route via your DHCP server (probably your router)